How to Forward gRPC Requests in a Proxy Server for Ray?
I am implementing a reverse proxy for Ray. The reverse proxy works well for HTTP requests, but some communications of Ray use gRPC. For example, the reverse proxy is getting requests like http://localhost:8265/ray.rpc.NodeInfoGcsService/GetClusterId
Here’s how I handle HTTP requests in the proxy:
from flask import Flask, request, Response
import requests
import logging
import urllib.parse
import grpc

app = Flask(__name__)
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

RAY_DASHBOARD_URL = "http://localhost:8265"

@app.route('/<path:path>', methods=['GET', 'POST', 'PUT', 'DELETE', 'PATCH'])
def proxy(path):
    url = f"{RAY_DASHBOARD_URL}/{path}"
    headers = {key: value for key, value in request.headers if key != 'Host'}
    query_string = urllib.parse.urlencode(request.args)
    if query_string:
        url = f"{url}?{query_string}"

    logger.info(f"Proxying request to {url}")

    if request.headers.get('Content-Type') == 'application/grpc':
        # TODO: Add GRPC forwarding logic here
        pass
    else:
        response = requests.request(
            method=request.method,
            url=url,
            headers=headers,
            data=request.get_data(),
            cookies=request.cookies,
            allow_redirects=False,
        )

        excluded_headers = ['content-encoding', 'content-length', 'transfer-encoding', 'connection']
        headers = [(name, value) for name, value in response.raw.headers.items() if name.lower() not in excluded_headers]

        return Response(response.content, response.status_code, headers)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)

Note that I escape the gRCP part on this snippet.
I have access to the generated GRPC files compiled from the proto configurations at ray.core.generated. I guess one could base the implementation on that, but it seems this would be reimplementing every route all over.
How can I simply forward the gRPC request from the reverse proxy at this stage?
Also, I tried connecting to the gRPC port, programmatically and using Postman, but I get method not found on all my requests.

You can replicate this by running a head node specifying the gRPC port like this:
ray start --head --dashboard-grpc-port=900

Then, from postman, I use the gcs_service.proto config file which you can find on ray/src/ray/protobuf, then define the path for imports which is just the root ray folder. Also, Postman will complain about some syntax errors, but it's just comments from the .proto file that it's failing to parse correctly. You can simply delete those comments to replicate the issue.
